# Updating a Value in a Loop

Tags: java

I'm having trouble updating `error` in the below code. I've included 2 classes below; the MadLib class and the MadLibRunner class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class MadLib
{
    ArrayList<String> nouns;
    ArrayList<String> adjectives;
    ArrayList<String> verbs;
    public MadLib()
    {
        nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
        adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();
        verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
        nouns.add("dog");
        nouns.add("pig");
        nouns.add("chicken");
        nouns.add("building");
        nouns.add("car");
        nouns.add("person");
        nouns.add("place");
        nouns.add("thing");
        nouns.add("truck");
        nouns.add("city");
        nouns.add("state");
        nouns.add("school");
        nouns.add("student");
        nouns.add("bird");
        nouns.add("turkey");
        nouns.add("lion");
        nouns.add("tiger");
        nouns.add("alligator");
        nouns.add("elephant");
        adjectives.add("blue");
        adjectives.add("green");
        adjectives.add("orange");
        adjectives.add("fat");
        adjectives.add("skinny");
        adjectives.add("tall");
        adjectives.add("funny");
        adjectives.add("mad");
        adjectives.add("glad");
        adjectives.add("happy");
        adjectives.add("silly");
        adjectives.add("purple");
        adjectives.add("big");
        adjectives.add("little");
        adjectives.add("tiny");
        adjectives.add("huge");
        verbs.add("run");
        verbs.add("fly");
        verbs.add("skip");
        verbs.add("climb");
        verbs.add("clean");
        verbs.add("smell");
        verbs.add("eat");
        verbs.add("cry");
        verbs.add("smile");
        verbs.add("laugh");
        verbs.add("jump");
        verbs.add("crank");
        verbs.add("program");
    }
    public String sentence (String statement)
    {
        String output = statement;
        String word = "";
        Random rand = new Random();
        String error = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (nouns.size() > 0 && adjectives.size() > 0 && verbs.size() > 0)
            {
                if (output.charAt(i) == '#')
                {
                    int random = rand.nextInt(nouns.size());
                    word = nouns.get(random);
                    nouns.remove(random);
                    output = output.substring(0, i) + word + (output.substring(i + 1));
                }
                else if (output.charAt(i) == '&')
                {
                    int random = rand.nextInt(adjectives.size());
                    word = adjectives.get(random);
                    adjectives.remove(random);
                    output = output.substring(0, i) + word + (output.substring(i + 1));
                }
                else if (output.charAt(i) == '@')
                {
                    int random = rand.nextInt(verbs.size());
                    word = verbs.get(random);
                    verbs.remove(random);
                    output = output.substring(0, i) + word + (output.substring(i + 1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int nounCount = nouns.size() - 1;
                int adjectiveCount = adjectives.size() - 1;
                int verbCount = verbs.size() - 1;
                if (nounCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns.";
                }
                else if (adjectiveCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough adjectives.";
                }
                else if (verbCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough verbs.";
                }
                else if (nounCount == 0 && adjectiveCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns and adjectives.";
                }
                else if (nounCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns and verbs.";
                }
                else if (adjectiveCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough adjectives and verbs.";
                }
                else if (nounCount == 0 && adjectiveCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
                {
                    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns, adjectives, and verbs.";
                }
                output = "Error: Not enough " + error;
                break;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And the runner class...

```
public class MadLibRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        boolean quit=false;
        MadLib prog = new MadLib();
        do
        {
            out.println("Welcome to MadLibs!\n Please input your coded sentence, or end to exit: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
            String statement = in.nextLine();
            if(statement.equals("end"))
                quit=true;
            else
                out.println(prog.sentence(statement));
        }while(!quit);
        out.println("\nThank you, goodbye.\n");
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `else` statement in the loop is to specify which parts of speech are missing. The issue I keep getting is `error` won't update at the end of the `for` loop in `MadLib`. I tried changing the initial value of `error` to test the output and it did return the test value of `error`. How can I get `error` to update in the loop?

Wow, I just realized I forgot to clarify something very important. I should be able to enter multiple sentences into the code, and each time the nouns/adjectives/verbs used are removed from the list. If there aren't enough of any of those parts of speech for the entire sentence during any iteration, then it should display an error message. The error message is what isn't working.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger if you want to understand what each line of code does.  If the `error` variable is not being changed, then none of your conditions are `true`

Comment: why would it enter that block of code? Your containers all contain entries (nouns, verbs etc.)

Comment: What does it prints if you add a `System.out.println(nounCount + " " + adjectiveCount + " " + verbCount);` after this line `int verbCount = verbs.size() - 1;`? I'm pretty sure it prints `-1`. So all your `if-else` are false since they are never equal to 0.

Comment: @Frakcool Does that mean I should remove the -1 for all the `Counts`?

Comment: @EruIlúvatar did it printed a `-1`? If so, then yes, you should remove it or change your `if` conditions as `<= 0` if that helped, let me know and I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @Frakcool All it does is print Error: Not enough

Comment: You never told me what it printed, I'm on mobile, can't compile right now, I'll check it later, it seems like an easy problem. Just let me get home to check it.

Comment: @Frakcool all right, thanks. FYI I just realized that I forgot to mention one essential thing in the description. I'll just put it here:

Comment: I should be able to enter multiple sentences into the code, and each time the nouns/adjectives/verbs used are removed from the list. If there aren't enough of any of those parts of speech for the entire sentence during any iteration, then it should display an error message. The error message is what isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Thank you very much. You were right about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is VERY verbose and is going to be prone to issues if you ever decide you want to have adverbs or something.

```
if (nounCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns.";
}
else if (adjectiveCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough adjectives.";
}
else if (verbCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough verbs.";
}
else if (nounCount == 0 && adjectiveCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns and adjectives.";
}
else if (nounCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns and verbs.";
}
else if (adjectiveCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough adjectives and verbs.";
}
else if (nounCount == 0 && adjectiveCount == 0 && verbCount == 0)
{
    error = error + "Error: Not enough nouns, adjectives, and verbs.";
}
output = "Error: Not enough " + error;
break;
```

I would restructure things so that you have your checks in with the replacement code.

```
String replacement;

if (output.charAt(i) == '#')
{
    if (nouns.size() > 0)
    {
        int random = rand.nextInt(nouns.size());
        replacement = nouns.get(random);
        nouns.remove(random);
    } else {
        return "Error: ran out of nouns";
    }
} else if  ...

output = output.substring(0, i) + replacement+ (output.substring(i + 1));
```

It's not perfect, but this way you can minimize the amount of specific error cases you have.  Also, you don't care if there are no adjectives if there are no adjective replacements in the sentence.

In it's current form, your code should work once you take off the `- 1`s since size is one based.  If there are no items in the list, the size will be 0, so your case would be `if (nouns.size() == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

When you construct `MadLib` you add nouns, verbs and adjectives. Hence the code where `error` is updated is never executed.

More precisely, the following expression always evaluates to true:

```
if (nouns.size() > 0 && adjectives.size() > 0 && verbs.size() > 0)
```

Hence the `else` block where `error` might be set is never entered.

Comment: That would make sense, but (I hope) I call the `MadLib` class twice; once to initiate prog and once to run `statement`.

Comment: @EruIlúvatar Not sure I follow. What do you mean "call the `MadLib` class twice"? Construct it? If so, it will operate the same way both times.

Comment: I initiate `prog` once and then call the `sentence` class once. Sorry if I didn't clarify that

Comment: `sentence` is a method, not a class. You can call it many times. Eventually one of your containers (nouns, adjectives, verbs) should empty and `error` will start being used. But you'll need to call it several times.